# Abort Controller in IE11 doesn't work. Any way to support it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, fetch, internet-explorer-11

Tried using 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/abortcontroller-polyfill?activeTab=readme to use this controller on IE. 
But it does not work

Comment: Please try to provide detailed information about your issue. Try to inform us if there is any error message or warning message. Try to post your sample code so that we can see what you are doing in your code. If you need to support browsers where fetch is not available at all (for example Internet Explorer 11), you first need to install a fetch polyfill and then import the abortcontroller-polyfill afterwards. Did you install it and follow the steps mentioned in the document?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get window.AbortController() running in IE11, take a look at their [IE11 example](https://github.com/mo/abortcontroller-polyfill-examples/tree/master/create-react-app-msie11).

Install:

- promise-polyfill
- unfetch
- abortcontroller-polyfill

Add the following to your work before AbortController is called.

```
import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill';
import 'unfetch/polyfill';
import 'abortcontroller-polyfill';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to figure this out. 

But later we got stuck in Safari version < 10 .. So :( :( we dropped the idea of using it later on.