# How to add polyfill for String.repeat function for ie11?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, create-react-app, polyfills

How would I add polyfill for String.repeat method for ie11? I am not using it directly in my code, it's probably some of the imported libs.

In IE console I get this error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'repeat'`

I also get `'AbortController' is undefined` which I am also not using my code, probably external lib again.

I am using create react app and I imported in index.js:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

I tried adding https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill to my index.js but it didn't do anything.

Did anyone else have similar problem?

Comment: Using that polyfill for IE works for me.

Comment: Have you imported the polyfill at the first line in index.js? Have you followed the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435589/starter-create-react-app-with-ie11-polyfill-import-still-aborts-in-ie11/56439822#56439822) to support react app in IE 11? Besides, you could use [this polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abortcontroller-polyfill) for `AbortController`. If still not working, please provide [a minimal, reproducible code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Answer (score 3):

To add a `String.repeat` polyfill for IE11, I suggest using the `core-js` library to polyfill missing features.

Install `core-js` by running the following command:

```js
npm install --save core-js@3.6.5
```

Inside of `src/index.js`, import the appropriate polyfill at the very top:

```js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'core-js/features/string/repeat';

import React from 'react';
// ...
```

---

As for `AbortController`, install it by running the following command:

```js
npm install --save abortcontroller-polyfill
```

Edit your `src/index.js` file to import it:

```js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'core-js/features/string/repeat';
import 'abortcontroller-polyfill';

import React from 'react';
// ...
```

- You don't need to install `promise-polyfill/src/polyfill` and `unfetch/polyfill` for `AbortController` since `create-react-apps` polyfills for IE11 already come with `Promise` and `fetch` polyfills

  - [Supporting Internet Explorer](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md#supporting-internet-explorer)
- If you are not using `create-react-app` IE11 polyfills, however, I suggest you check out the following answer:

  - [Abort Controller in IE11 doesn't work. Any way to support it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57485231/5862900)

Answer (score 0):

This is for IE's ES6 incompatibility issues.

Add following polyfills with npm

```
promise-polyfill
unfetch
abortcontroller-polyfill
```

and import them like

```
import Promise from "promise-polyfill";
import fetch from 'unfetch';
import 'abortcontroller-polyfill';
```

for `Abortcontroller`

& For `Object.repeat`
Copy and paste MDN's polyfill code into very first of you JS file.
That will do.

**EDIT**
For React this should look like this *(you can do it in `index.js`)*

```
// import polyfills
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';

import Promise from "promise-polyfill";
import fetch from 'unfetch';
import 'abortcontroller-polyfill';
```